# Calculator Shortcuts for Derivative?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a TI-84 and I am in a business calculus class.

Our teacher doesn't give us much time on tests and I am a bit slow so I was wondering if there was any way to do some of these problems on the calculator to make things faster.

For example, Find the derivative of: $y = \frac{3}{x}-\frac{x}{2}$

I have multiple choice and the answer seems to be: $\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{-3}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2}$

Is there any way to get that answer in the calculator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to find symbolic derivatives (i.e. unevaluated derivatives) on a TI-84. Some newer calculators have that capability (like the TI-Nspire), but the TI-84 is limited to numerical approximations. More information [here](http://brownmath.com/ti83/deriv.htm).

For the derivative in question, just use the power rule. The function $$y=\frac{3}{x}-\frac{x}{2}$$ can be rewritten $$y=3x^{-1}-\frac{x^1}{2}$$ Just multiply each term by the exponent, and subtract one. $3x^{-1}$ becomes $-3x^{-2}$, and $\frac{x^1}{2}$ becomes $\frac{x^0}{2}$.